# Docker-compose returned a non-zero code: 100

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian, dockerfile

I'm getting an issue with docker during build.

When the process arrives to my nginx image builder it throws me an error like this:

> E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes ERROR:
>   Service 'nginx' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get
>   update && apt-get install -y     nginx    openssl' returned a non-zero
>   code: 100

This is how my Dockerfile starts:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    nginx \
    openssl
```

I have no idea about this error. Some help would be appreciated.

I'm working over Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: whats your host os? I build your docker file successfully

Comment: The actual error message will be before what you quoted in the question.

Comment: Incredible, today when i wake up i try to build anothertime and this time is working prefectly. Should be a problem with my internet connection.